# MVC Razor view make image invisible based on model item condition

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have some razor code like:

```
foreach (var item in projectGroup) {
                <tr>
                    ...
                    <td>
                        <label id="@( "fieldapprovallabel" + @item.InvoiceLineId)">@item.FieldUserName</label>
                        @if(item.FieldApproved != null) {
                            <img src="../../Content/Images/stock_lock.gif" alt="locked" class="lockicon" />
                        }
                    </td>
...
}
```

So basically the lock image is only visible based on a condition. I understand it is not good to have logic like this in the view. Can anyone suggest a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is anything wrong with simple boolean logic or null checking in the view.

The only alternative would be to hide it all in some helper class that would return the html (or an empty string), which I think adds unnecessary complexity in a simple case like this.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a view model with a property called `IsLocked`. This abstracts the business logic used to make the "IsLocked" determination, and doesn't state how the view should behave, just informs the view that the item is in a particular state.

The subsequent binding code would be similar, but doesn't require the view to know that `item.FieldApproved` equals a locked condition.

Of course, in the context of your application `item.FieldApproved` may already be a clean separation of concerns, in which case I think it's fine as is.